# Docker splunk logging driver - handshake failure

Tags: docker, splunk

I'm trying to use docker splunk logging driver. Here's my command and docker error message:

```
$ docker run --log-driver=splunk --log-opt splunk-token=XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX --log-opt splunk-url=https://input-prd-p-pxxxxxxxxxx.cloud.splunk.com:8088 hello-world

docker: Error response from daemon: Failed to initialize logging driver: remote error: handshake failure.
```

I've also tested with `--log-opt splunk-insecureskipverify=true`, but it didn't help. The splunk Http even collector should be configured correctly, as I can succesfully use curl for logging:

```
curl -k https://input-prd-p-pxxxxxxxxxx.cloud.splunk.com:8088/services/collector/event -H 'Authorization: Splunk XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX' -d '{"event":"Hello, World!"}'
```

Any clues how to make splunk docker driver work?

Here's my docker setup:

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.12.1
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   23cf638
 Built:        Thu Aug 18 17:32:24 2016
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64
 Experimental: true

Server:
 Version:      1.12.1
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   23cf638
 Built:        Thu Aug 18 17:32:24 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same issue.  Found this post regarding the self-signed certificate being the issue used in the trial version of the cloud instance:

https://answers.splunk.com/answers/335933/http-event-collector-how-to-troubleshoot-why-im-ge.html

That would explain why curl is working (-k option) and Docker is not.

> -k, --insecure
>
> (SSL) This option explicitly allows curl to perform "insecure" SSL
>   connections and transfers. All SSL connections are attempted to be
>   made secure by using the CA certificate bundle installed by default.
>   This makes all connections considered "insecure" fail unless -k,
>   --insecure is used.

Based on the aforementioned post and replies within it from Splunk, Splunk has not fixed the issue as of July.

You would think even with the flag of "splunk-insecureskipverify=true", that would be a workaround for testing...

I have yet to find a workaround.

Comment: OK, that looks like the root cause for this problem. [Splunk has said on Feb 24 / 2016](https://answers.splunk.com/answers/335933/http-event-collector-how-to-troubleshoot-why-im-ge.html#comment-371925) that they are working on the problem. It seems it's not on the high-priority list ;)